# Empty referer on laravel Request::server('HTTP_REFERER')

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get the previos page  on laravel to check if it's coming from an outside web page, but the referer is empty

```
 public function index()
    {
        $referer = Request::server('HTTP_REFERER');
```

There i s another way to know what is the previos  visited page??

Comment: What does `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` return you?

Comment: The same  result null too

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is temporary object. Once you refresh page `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` will reset its value.  There is another options to redirect back using `return redirect()->back()`

Comment: @afccc How are you testing? Just visit the page from any outside URL and check. Also note that `HTTP_REFERER` isn't reliable. It does give a correct referer however it can be tweaked.

Comment: I'm on an outside web like google, the I type  my web url (on local) and then I see on the debug that the referer is empty

Comment: try `$referrer = $this->request->headers->get('referer');` to get referer

Comment: @afccc Referer doesn't get attached when you type in the URL. You have to visit the page through some external anchor link on some other page.

Comment: have you trired Request::headers->get('referer')?

Comment: I get an error  `$this->request` doesn't exists on my controller

Comment: @Sehdev Request::headers doesn't exists

Comment: @afccc Make a dummy anchor link on some page say `http://localhost/test.html` which has the link as `<a href='your_laravel_link_url'>My Laravel page</a>` and in your Laravel controller add `dd($_SERVER);` and see what you get.

Comment: try request()->headers->get('referer'); if you have injected  $request injected into your function

Comment: @vivek_23 I setted up a dummy anchor on an outside web but I get  the same result, referer is null

Comment: @afccc See this link https://imgur.com/a/90ATfpk

Answer (score 0):

Your method is right, but you probably forget to use

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Then you can use it on your controller like this

```
 $referer = Request::server('HTTP_REFERER');
```